# How do I reset ratbagctl settings?

Tags: mouse, display-resolution, brightness, logitech

I used `ratbagctl` because I want to change some settings of my Logitech G102 Mouse, but I want to restore the settings of the LED. What should I do? I have given information about my mouse below.

```
$ ratbagctl warbling-mara info
warbling-mara - Logitech G102 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse
             Model: usb:046d:c092:0
 Number of Buttons: 6
    Number of Leds: 1
Number of Profiles: 1
Profile 0: (active)
  Name: n/a
  Report Rate: 1000Hz
  Resolutions:
    0: 400dpi (active)
    1: 800dpi (default)
    2: 1600dpi
    3: 3200dpi
    4: 0dpi
  Button: 0 is mapped to 'button 1'
  Button: 1 is mapped to 'button 2'
  Button: 2 is mapped to 'button 3'
  Button: 3 is mapped to 'button 4'
  Button: 4 is mapped to 'button 5'
  Button: 5 is mapped to 'resolution-cycle-up'
  LED: 0, depth: rgb, mode: cycle, duration: 4500, brightness: 255
```

Comment: Can you not just run the program again and  change the settings?

Comment: The default RGB animation on my mouse was wave but in `ratbagctl` there is only breathing and cycle. I want to bring it back to wave animation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after making the settings with G Hub in Windows, I turned on the on-board mode and selected the profile I wanted, and my problem was solved.